# How to turn off collision in HaxeFlixel

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel, haxelib

Im making a brick breaker like game and when I try to remove the brick, I remove the sprite, but not the collision. In new to HaxeFlixel so I don't have a clue why this is happening. Can somebody please help me? (code below)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `remove()` function removes the object from the state, which is causing the odd behavior. You only want to disable the object.

Try changing the line `remove(brick)` to instead `brick.kill()` and see if that resolves your collision problem.